# bash script to echo a single file in a folder

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write s bash script that will be run from within a oozie workflow in a Hadoop cluster.

I have a series of folders that each one has a single file in it.  The name of the file is generated and therefore unknown to me at the time of execution of the script. I need a script that I can pass in the path of the folder and have it echo the file that is contained in the folder.  The folder will only contain one file.

Comment: "I need a script that ..." without showing any attempt to write it yourself is not an on-topic question.

Comment: `that I can pass in the path of the folder and have it echo the file that is contained in the folder` well, just `echo folder/*`

Comment: `for folder in "${@:-.}"; do printf '%s\n' "$folder"/*; done` (or you can use `echo "$folder"/*` if you don't think you'll run into problems with peculiar names and peculiar implementations of `echo). It takes the command line arguments, substituting `.` (the current directory) if you omitted all arguments, and echoes the names of all the files in all the directories.  If, as you say, the directories each only contain one file, there'll be no repetition of the directory names (unless you list a directory twice on the command line).  You have to work harder to verify 1 file per directory.

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm uncertain what you mean by "echo the file"...

If you want the contents of the file:

```
for fn in <yourfolder>/*; do
    cat "${fn}"
done
```

If you want only the file name:

```
for fn in <yourfolder>/*; do
    echo -e "${fn}"
done
```